# How to append two lists of numbers using a for loop?

Tags: loops, append

I am trying to take the list list_of_numbers and identify which of the numbers are even perfect squares and which are odd perfect squares, but I am not getting any output when I run this. expected output would be two lists
first list: number_odd_squares [9, 25, 81, 121]
second list: number_even_squares [2, 16, 36, 42, 64, 100]

list_of_numbers = [2, 9, 16, 25, 36, 42, 64, 81, 100, 121]

def find_perfect_squares(list_of_numbers):

```
number_even_squares =[]
number_odd_squares = []

for i in list_of_numbers:
    if (i%2) != 0 and root = math.sqrt(i):
        number_odd_squares.append(i)
    elif (i%2) == 0 and root = math.sqrt(i):
        number_even_squares.append(i)
        
print(number_even_squares)
print(number_odd_squares)

return
```

find_perfect_squares(list_of_numbers)

Comment: What's the expected output? Can you put it in the question, please?

Comment: edited what i have now and what my expected output is

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you aren't actually iterating through your array, you are iterating from `0` to the length of the array, which is `[0, 1, 2, ...]` instead of `[2, 9, 16, ...]`, so look at changing the `range(len(...))` part.

Also, you are never using your `i` variable which is getting set in the loop. It is probably meant to go in the `if/else` block, where you are checking `1 % 2`(which is never equal to `0`).

Look at those 2 errors, and it should help your program run as intended.